# Why won't my overloaded, static method recognize my height parameter?

Tags: java, methods, static, overloading

So I have three static, overloaded methods that are used in my AreaClient class that are taking input from the user and passing what those inputs are as parameters to the methods below. For some reason though I can't seem to get the last area method to take in my hieght variable as a parameter. I keep getting an error saying "cannot find symbol". These are supposed to be overloaded methods, just what the assignment says. Sorry if this is real simple but I am pretty new to programming. Here is the code that I wrote.

```
import java.util.Scanner;    // Needed for the Scanner class

public class AreaClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 double circleRadius;           //input for radius of circle
 int width, length;             //input for rectangle width and length
 double cylinderRadius, height; //input for radius of a cylinder and hieght

 // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 // gathering input for radius of circle
 System.out.println("Enter radius of circle");
 circleRadius = keyboard.nextDouble();

 // input for width and length of rectangle
 System.out.println("Enter width of rectangle");
 width = keyboard.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter length of rectangle");
 length = keyboard.nextInt();

 // input for radius and hieght of cylinder
 System.out.println("Enter radius of cylinder");
 cylinderRadius = keyboard.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("Enter hieght of cylinder");
 height = keyboard.nextDouble();

 //returning area methods results and storing them in new variables
 double circleArea = area(circleRadius);
 int rectangleArea = area(width, length);
 double cylinderArea = area(cylinderRadius, height);

 //displaying results of methods
 System.out.println("The area of your circle is: " + circleArea);
 System.out.println("The area of your rectangle is: " + rectangleArea);
 System.out.println("The area of your cylinger is: " + cylinderArea);
}


//overloaded methods that take different inputs
public static double area(double r)
{
  return 3.14159265359 * Math.pow(r, 2);
}

public static int area(int w, int l)
{
  return w * l;
}

//actual method that doesn't recognize h inside
public static double area(double r, double h)
{
  return 2*3.14159265359 * Math.pow(r,2) + h (2*3.14159265359*r);
}


}
```

And the error msg I am getting

```
AreaClient.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
  return 2*3.14159265359 * Math.pow(r,2) + h (2*3.14159265359*r);
                                           ^
symbol:   method h(double)
location: class AreaClient
1 error
```

Thanks guys. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean: `h * (2*3.14159265359*r)`. Without the operator, Java thinks you're trying to call a method named `h(double)`

```
return 2*3.14159265359 * Math.pow(r,2) + h * (2*3.14159265359*r);
```

Comment: It's working for me, thanks paul. For some reason I thought it would just multiply but it makes sense that it would be calling a method.

Comment: Computers aren't as good at inferring syntax as humans.  Best bet is to always be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Notice in the error message:

```
symbol:   method h(double)
```

Why it is looking for a method called `h()` which accepts a double?  Because you're telling it to:

```
h (2*3.14159265359*r)
```

`h` isn't a method, it's just a value.  You need to use an operator to connect it to that other value.  I think you meant to do this:

```
h * (2*3.14159265359*r)
```